# Blazor Webassembly: Elements keep disappearing when doing drag and drop operation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, blazor

Big fan of your work.

I am building a Blazor WASM application utilizing the HTML5 Drag and Drop API. I am having the strangest issue that I've been trying to fix for hours.

This app allows one to put objects into "groups". A group can contain other groups, and so on.

I've got it mostly working, but two issues are leaving me scratching my head.

**SOLVED** See comment 1) When I drag a group UP from underneath into another group, the group is migrated into the destination but the subitems in the original group disappear.

Before I drag the bottom group up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCsCr.png

After:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIWA6.png

2. When I drag a group DOWN from above into another group, the destination group's GUID overwrites the source and I am left with one group.

Before:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuTIP.png

After:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/26u27.png

Groups are the orange shapes, Interfaces are the blue shapes. They are rendered via the Field class.

I've tried every permutation of the code I can think of and nothing has made it any better. I must be missing something here.

```html
Group.razor

@inherits Item

<div id=@Uid class="tb-group tb-draggable @CssClass" 
        draggable = "true"
        ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
        @ondragstart:stopPropagation
        @ondragstart="@(()=>HandleOnDragStart(this))"
        @ondragend="HandleOnDragEnd"
        @ondragenter="HandleOnDragEnter"
        @ondragleave="HandleOnDragLeave"
        @ondrop:stopPropagation
        @ondrop="HandleOnDrop"
        @onclick:stopPropagation
        @onclick="Debug_Output">@Title : @Uid : @Parent.Uid

        @foreach(Item item in Items){
            
            if(item.GetType() == typeof(Group)){
                <Group Uid=@item.Uid Title="@item.Title" Field=@Field Parent=@this></Group>
            } else if(item.GetType() == typeof(Interface)){
                <Interface Uid=@item.Uid Title="@item.Title" Field=@Field Parent=@this></Interface>
            }
            
        }
          
 </div>
```

**This code is responsible for OnDrop behavior (HandleOnDrop)**

```cs
Group.razor.cs - 

    public partial class Group : Item {
     
        public List<Item> Items;

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>();
            base.OnInitialized();
        }

        public void HandleOnDrop(){
            if(Payload.Uid != this.Uid){
                Console.WriteLine("Removing item " + Payload.Uid);
                Items.Add(Payload);
                Payload.Parent.Items.Remove(Payload.Parent.Items.Find(x => x.Uid == Payload.Uid));
            }
            CssClass = "";
            this.Field.Refresh();
            Payload.Parent = this;
            
        }
...
```

```html
Interface.razor

@inherits Item

<div id=@Uid draggable="true" class="tb-interface tb-draggable @CssClass" 
            @ondragstart:stopPropagation   
            @ondragstart="@(()=>HandleOnDragStart(this))"
            @onclick:stopPropagation>@Title : @Uid : @Parent.Uid</div>
```

**Could it be how I initialize these components (via constructor)? Maybe they're getting cleaned up by the GC?**

```cs
Field.razor.cs - 

    public partial class Field : Group {
        
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
            
        }

        public void AddGroup(){
            Group grp = new Group();
            grp.Parent = this;
            Items.Add(grp);
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        public void AddInterface(){
            Interface iface = new Interface();
            iface.Parent = this;
            Items.Add(iface);
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        public void Refresh(){
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
```

I'm at my wits end here. If anyone could give me some advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I resolved issue #1. I wasn't passing in the Items to the Group object on instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1: Needed to pass the Items object into Group on instantiation

Issue #2: Needed to use @key to maintain reference